# HTML tags are displayed in Twig as a string, not as HTML tags

Tags: php, twig

I pass the variable from PHP to Twig that contains HTML tags. As example my method code:

```
public function test(string $string): string
{
    return '<span>' . $string . '</span>';
}
```

I deduce this method in Twig:

```
<div>{{ test('abc') }}</div>
```

Output on page: `<span>abc</span>` instead of the usual `abc`

I need to solve this problem on the side of PHP code without using any twig filters or functions (without `raw` or `autoescape false`).

I tried to look at the code of the `raw` method in Twig module, but everything is very confusing there and I couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: Is this a function inside a TwigExtension?

Comment: In class `Escaper` function `twig_raw_filter`

Comment: Can you show me how u define it? If it's a filter/function you can mark the function as safe by doing the following `new \Twig\TwigFunction('test', [ $this, 'test, ], [ 'is_safe' => [ 'html', ],]);`